# Pass string with space using Yargs

Tags: yargs

I am using yargs to collect any arguments passed. My scenario is to be able to pass a string with spaces with double quotes just like this:

```
./nodeFile.js -n "my node module"
```

But it actually takes `"my` as the argument value for `yargs.argv.n` and put the remaining string in `_`. I know it works when we use escape characters with `"` but I cannot assume this is obvious for my user.

Can anyone please help me to find if there is any configuration or any hack using which I can collect entire string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yargs takes only the first word of commandline input string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915586/yargs-takes-only-the-first-word-of-commandline-input-string)

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't solve for me. As mentioned in the question, I tried it using double-quotes(also tried with single-quotes but got no luck)

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Also stuck on this.